# Multiple terminal setup in single VSCode project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project where I'm using a PowerShell terminal for frontend, and WSL terminal for backend. My workflow on opening the project is:

- Open terminal (defaults to PowerShell), run `cd frontend`, then `npm run dev`
- Open WSL terminal tab, `cd backend`, `rails s`

Is it possible to have the terminal open with both of these tabs open by default? Already in the required directory would be great but not a dealbreaker.

Fine with using an extension if it's not possible natively in VSCode.

Comment: have you searched the marketplace for `terminal`

Comment: yes, I have. couldn't find anything which explicitly states it does this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.vscode/tasks.json` file and put the following content inside:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "frontend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cd frontend && npm run dev",
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "group": "dev"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "backend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cd backend && rails s",
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      },
      "options": {
        "shell": {
          "executable": "wsl"
        }
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "group": "dev"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the same folder create a `settings.json` as follows:

```json
{
  "task.allowAutomaticTasks": "on"
}
```

The latter can also be automated with the `Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks` command from the palette.

I'm not 100% sure the WSL part will work as I don't have a WSL instance installed; if it doesn't work that way, you can try passing the `cd` and `rails s`  as `args` inside the `shell` object.

So in the end the project structure would look like this:

```
your-project
├─.vscode
│   settings.json
│   tasks.json
├─backend
└─frontend
```

Also, don't forget to trust the workspace when asked, otherwise the automatic tasks won't work.

Comment: Perfect! Just to note that the commands (for both terminals) needed to be separated with `;`, not `&&`. I just tried to edit the answer but got a 'too many pending edits' error

Comment: Cool, glad to help, and in turn thank you for the correction. I guess the separators used depend on the shell you're using and how it handles consecutive commands.

Comment: Actually the WSL one didn't work. When it first failed I tried changing the separator on a WSL terminal which was already open so I assumed that was the only failure.

Just tried to run again and it gives `command not found: rails`

I changed the command to `cd backend && ls` and it lists the backend directory correctly, and from the wsl shell, not powershell, so I'm not sure why it can't run `rails`